# ip address networks in Python 3.3

Tags: python, networking, ip-address

I am trying to convert a group of IP ranges that can start and end on any given address, but not necessarily on a .0, .127, or .255, etc.  I have code that is mostly working; however, it can be slow for large ranges.

For example `find_range("1.40.0.0","1.44.255.255")` will take over a minute to return the correct result of `1.40.0.0/14` and `1.44.0.0/16`.

Also, I am have trouble when the starting range does not end with a .0.  How can I fix these 2 issues: slowness on large IP ranges and when the starting range does not end in .0?

For the slowness problem, I tried skipping more than 1 address at a time, but then this would miss smaller ranges.

```
import ipaddress, socket, struct

def ip2int(addr):                                                               
    return struct.unpack("!I", socket.inet_aton(addr))[0]                       

def int2ip(addr):                                                               
    return socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("!I", addr))        

def ipminus(ip, amount=1):
    tmp = ip2int(ip)
    return int2ip(tmp - amount)

def ipplus(ip):
    tmp = ip2int(ip)
    return int2ip(tmp + 1)

def cidr_notation(a,b):
    for mask in range(32, 6, -1):
        test = "%s/%s" % (a,mask)
        try:
            n = ipaddress.IPv4Network(test,False)
            if b == "%s" % (n.broadcast_address):
                return test
        except:
            pass
    return None

def split_range(a,b):
    a1 = ip2int(a)
    b1 = ip2int(b)

    needed = 1
    while needed:
        result = cidr_notation(a,b)
        if result:
            print( "* %16s\t%16s\t%16s" % (result, a, b))
            if ip2int(b) > b1:
                needed = 0
            else:
                a = ipplus(b)
                b = int2ip(b1)
        else:
            b = ipminus(b)

    return result

def find_range(x,y):
    result = cidr_notation(x,y)
    if result:
        print( "# %16s\t%16s\t%16s" % (result, x, y))
    else:
        split_range(x,y)

# main...
print("%16s\t%16s\t%16s" % ("mask","start","end"))
print("%16s\t%16s\t%16s" % ("----","-----","---"))

find_range("128.191.0.0","128.191.255.255") #fast
find_range("10.55.96.106","10.55.96.106") #fast
find_range("5.135.14.0","5.135.61.11") #slow
find_range("4.31.64.72","4.59.175.255") #does not work, how to fix?
find_range("1.40.0.0","1.44.255.255") #very slow
# 5000 more find_range() calls...
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at this existing code from ipaddress.py? https://code.google.com/p/ipaddress-py/source/browse/ipaddress.py#248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on bsdlp's comment, this code got a lot simpler and faster!

```
    def find_range(x,y,c_code="",c_name=""):
    print()
    print("%29s\t%23s" % (x,y))
    print("%16s\t%16s\t%16s\t%4s\t%s" % ("mask","start","end","code","name"))
    print("%16s\t%16s\t%16s\t%4s\t%s" % ("----","-----","---","----","----"))

    result = ipaddress.summarize_address_range( ipaddress.IPv4Address(x), ipaddress.IPv4Address(y) )
    for entry in result:
        net = str( entry.network_address )
        bcast = str( entry.broadcast_address )
        print( "%16s\t%16s\t%16s\t%4s\t%s" % (entry, net, bcast,c_code,c_name))
```